# ODBC Command does not provide the count of inserted records

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, odbc

I am using an ODBC connnection to connect to a database. When I execute `OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` with an insert statement, the records are inserted into the table, but the method returns 0.

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of records affected. It's working fine in case of Delete and Update but not working in case of Insert.

```
query = "Insert into table1 (field1, field2) values (1,2)";

OdbcConnection = _remoteconn = new OdbcConnection(constring);
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, _remoteconn);
recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be normal since there are no records to affect? They are only just created...

Comment: But in sql server it gives the no of inserted records count.

Comment: could you please add your Insert statement on your post.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ODBC is not a driver - it is a wrapper around a driver. The answer to this question is going to depend on the underlying ODBC driver that you are using, which would typically be specified in the Connection String.

The MSDN documentation is really more of an expectation or a suggestion, but the ODBC interface cannot force the driver to return a particular result. It may be that the driver has some optimizations or settings which are interfering with your results, not unlike SQL Servers NO COUNT setting (which would override a driver's attempts to report affected rows, etc).

See wikipedia for a more thorough explanation of how ODBC works:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC

> *"Because different technologies have different capabilities, most ODBC drivers do not implement all functionality defined in the ODBC standard. Some drivers offer extra functionality not defined by the standard."*

If you tell us which driver you are using, it may help to find a solution.

---

**EDIT**

To the best of my knowledge, the ODBC API function in question is the SQLRowCount function, as defined here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711835(v=vs.85).aspx

According to the ODBC standard, this function must be implemented for a driver to be considered ODBC-compliant. (That is not to say that the function will return the expected or correct result, just that it's there).

According the [Transoft documentation (page 67)](http://pz.southware.com/nlhtml/USQL_User_Guide.pdf) I've been able to dig up  the SQLRowCount function was implemented. There is no mention of this function in any way being disabled or of any required configuration.

Given the above, I would contact the vendor directly. It would appear that there is an error in their implementation or an undocumented "feature".

Comment: I am using transoft odbc drivers. can you tell me the behavior of this in this case.

Comment: @Romil - Unfortunately, I have no experience with that vendor. But it sounds like they have drivers to connect to many different data sources. You may want to check the documentation on their site for the specific driver you are using (looks like docs can be found here: http://www.transoft.com/support/product-knowledgebase.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help. I convinced the client on behalf of your answer. +1 for you.

Comment: @RomilKumarJain - It's been a few years, but I'm curious if you ever determined whether or not this was a vendor issue. Was it patched?

Comment: @JDB I have moved to some other project, so I have no update regarding that.
Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and it was because the ODBC Driver for the database in question had a different version from the database.

Check the version in the database with:

```
select @@version
```

and in the ODBC (at least for windows xp) at:

> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Microsoft ODBC Source
>   Administrator -> Drivers -> here check the column version of your
>   database

---

If they are different, that might be the problem!

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN for OdbcCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.executenonquery.aspx) states the following:

```
For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.
```

Can you post more code ? You're most certainly losing track of the number you get, *or* no records are being inserted (!!)

**UPDATE**

Or, as correctly pointed out in comments, the ODBC driver itself is either bugged or simply not providing this functionality (you're not given the count of records you'd expect).

Comment: The MSDN documentation is misleading. The writer was overly optimistic in believing that all or the vast majority of ODBC driver implementations would fully implement all recommendations. In practice very few drivers implement all recommendations. 

The statement that Romil's code is "almost certainly" at fault is far too strong - there's not enough evidence provided to diagnose the issue here.

Comment: Edited to include the "driver is bugged" option (didn't think about it) and rephrased

Comment: It is possible that the driver is bugged. However, we do not know what data source he's connecting to, so it's possible that it's not a bug but a feature. Perhaps counting inserted records would incur significant overhead and the driver has disabled this feature in favor of responsiveness. It may even be possible to turn record counting on and off via a configuration file. Until we know which driver is being used there's really no telling what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ExecuteReader
```

instead of

```
ExecuteNonQuery
```

and get the value with a select in the SQL sentence

Comment: I am doing INSERT, so how to use ExecuteReader for insertion.

Comment: Do INSERT and then SELECT for changes, or use stored procedures.

Comment: My question is that Why I am not getting count with ExecuteNonQuery for only Insert Statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

   class myOdbc
   {
      static void Main()
      {

      OdbcConnection myOdbcCommandConnection = new OdbcConnection("..."); 

      myOdbcCommandConnection.Open();

      OdbcCommand myOdbcCommand = myOdbcCommandConnection.CreateCommand();

      myOdbcCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) VALUES (?, ?)";

      myOdbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@field1", OdbcType.Int);
      myOdbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@field2", OdbcType.Int);

      myOdbcCommand.Parameters["@field1"].Value = 1;
      myOdbcCommand.Parameters["@field2"].Value = 2;

      Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows Affected is: {0}", myOdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());

      myOdbcCommandConnection.Close();

      Console.ReadKey();

      }
   }
```

Comment: Data is being inserted in database with my code but only the issue is that I am not getting count.

Comment: I get the count for updated record but not for inserted records.

Comment: I get for ALL affected records !

Comment: I am using transoft drivers. you are using different one.